# How to set auto login in windows 8 app

Tags: authentication, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I need to keep a auto login to my windows8 app. When user login with email and password i need to store in local and next time when app opened those details need to be auto filled.
I am new to these apps so please provide some code lines

Thanks
Ak

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own login functionality from scratch you could use the Microsoft account sign in. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj193591.aspx
and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh968445(v=win.10).aspx